# Types in object destructuring

Tags: typescript, destructuring

This

```
const { foo: IFoo[] } = bar;
```

and this

```
const { foo: Array<IFoo> } = bar;
```

will reasonably cause an error.

And this

```
const { foo: TFoo } = bar;
```

will just destructure `TFoo` property.

How can types be specified for destructured object properties?

Comment: Good question, but isn't it going to be able to infer the type from the definition of `bar` anyway?

Comment: The @user663031 comment should be removed as it is misleading.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha The article is unavailable, but most articles can be googled by article title. It was moved to https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript . It sheds some light indeed.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

It turns out it's possible to specify the type after `:` for the whole destructuring pattern:

```
const {foo}: {foo: IFoo[]} = bar;
```

Which in reality is not any better than plain old

```
const foo: IFoo[] = bar.foo;
```

Comment: But `{foo}` is not a value. It is what is usually called a "deconstructing assignment pattern". What you are seeing here is actually a special TypeScript feature which allows types of be associated with such patterns.

Comment: Indeed, it's more like a special case, especially compared to `let x, y, z: string` which apparently specifies type for `z` only. I updated the answer.

Comment: The first one will be better if you need to do multiple destructuring. But the line would get so ugly that it might be better on separate lines.

Answer (score 102):

If you don't mind using an interface when destructuring:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const obj: any = { name: 'Johnny', age: 25 };
const { name, age }: User = obj;
```

The types of properties `name` and `age` should be correctly inferred to `string` and `number` respectively.

Comment: It's a rare case when you would like to use an interface for every destruction.

Comment: @RA. What do you mean?

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 I think he means "destructuring," and the idea is that destructured values may not always have a Type or Interface backing them.

Answer (score 23):

#### [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) TypeScript example

I had scenarios like so:

```
const { _id } = req.query
if (_id.substr(2)) { 
 ...
}
```

in which the `req.query` was typed like

```
type ParsedUrlQuery = { [key: string]: string | string[] }
```

so doing this worked:

```
const { _id } = req.query as { _id: string }
if (_id.substr(2)) { 
 ...
}
```

The irony of this is Typescript was correct and I should have done:

```
const _id = String(req.query._id) ✅
```

Comment: how would the "correct way" work if you were destructuring multiple things?

Comment: `const { _id, abc, xyz } = req.query` and I think those vars would be of type `string | string[] | undefined` but I didn't verify.

Answer (score 14):

A follow-up to my own question.

**Types don't need to be specified for object properties, because they are inferred from the destructured object.**

Considering that `bar` was typed properly, `foo` type will be inferred:

```
const bar = { foo: [fooValue], ... }; // bar type is { foo: IFoo[], ... }
...
const { foo } = bar; // foo type is IFoo[]
```

Even if `bar` wasn't correctly typed (`any` or `unknown`), its type can be asserted:

```
const { foo } = bar as { foo: IFoo[] }; // foo type is IFoo[]
```

Comment: This is true only when destructuring a typed object. If destructing something that came in as `any` then you need to type either that or the destructed variables.

Comment: @SamuelNeff True, this is what the second snippet shows. The idea here is that it's beneficial to switch from untyped to typed code asap, in this case it's done before destructuring.

Comment: Completely agree; the more everything is properly typed, the better TS will pick up type info automatically, and happier devs will be.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to destructor and rename:

```
const {foo: food}: {foo: IFoo[]} = bar;
```

It took me a second to get the above right.

Comment: Re *"destructor"*: Don't you mean *"[destructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment)"*?

Answer (score 0):

It comes in handy when you're using multiple variables. If the function return is typed, the destructure is typed, without any need for defining a separate return type:

```js
function getBananaDetail<detailType>(...args): { name: string, detail: detailType } {
//...
}
const { name, detail } = getBanana<number>()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to assign types while destructuring:

```
const {foo} : {foo: IFoo[]} = bar;
```