# Unpack array argument directly to parameters?

Tags: arrays, typescript, parameters, destructuring

I know I can do this:

```
function (value: [boolean, string]) {
   const [boolValue, stringValue] = value;

   // make use of boolValue and stringValue
}
```

But am I able to do something like this?

```
// doesn't work
function ([boolValue: boolean, stringValue: string]) {
   // make use of boolValue and stringValue
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? It's fine in ES6 (without the types), so this appears to be a TS issue.

Comment: @Bergi it gives a lot of errors doing it that way; seems like invalid syntax. First error is `] expected` (instead of `:`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Types in object destructuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672807/types-in-object-destructuring)

Comment: @Bergi Just so you know, I don't think I agree about removing the ES6 tag. This isn't pure ES6, but I'm compiling to ES6. That makes a difference. Maybe it doesn't matter too much in this one case, but just because something is in TypeScript doesn't mean it doesn't have anything to do with ECMAScript.

Comment: @Sahuagin I'd argue that the question is only about the type error, which is a typescript-only topic. The compilation target hardly makes a difference for that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, might as well post as an answer. This works:

```
function ([boolValue, stringValue]: [boolean, string]) {
   // make use of boolValue and stringValue
}
```

Comment: Covered quite well at https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/13/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript.

Comment: I had to wrestle with the compiler to get this to work, it was convinced that the argument [true, 'foo'] was (boolean|string)[]. I had to explicitly cast it to [boolean, string].