# Enforcing TSX prop type inline for function declaration which declares props using object destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object-destructuring

I have a custom Type

```
export class MyClass {
  name: string;
  img: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.img = `/images/${name}.jpg`;
  }
}
```

I have a stateless functional component which takes that type as a parameter

```
export default (issue: Issue) => {
...
}
```

And when I try to create that stateless functional component

```
<MagazineCard issue={issues[0] as Issue} />
```

I get the error

```
Type '{ issue: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Issue'.
```

---

**There is a solution below, but I felt I should leave this material up for other's who might see this question for alternative solutions and deeper understanding**

[Object destructuring when initializing the JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312722/6331353), ex:

```
<MagazineCard {...issues[0]} />
```

[Create an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401351/6331353) for the arguments of my stateless functional component.

> Note: [types don't need to be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60243700/6331353)

**Proptypes**

```
MagazineCard.propTypes = {
  issue: Issue
}
```

Comment: `(issue)` and `({issue})` are very different. You can write `({issue}: {issue: Issue})` but I suspect that you know that and are looking for something else.

Comment: Yeah, I got another error when using `({issue})`, I left it how it was cause I'm new to typescript and wasn't sure what the correct method was anyway

Comment: But that is the correct form. You can't use `(issue)` it would be more than a TypeScript error, it would fail at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it's done

```
export default ({issue} : {issue : Issue}) => (
    //...Your JSX component
)
```

I was confused because it seemed over complicated to me, so I [made a post on reddit asking why this is the syntax for doing it](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/ghwggh/whats_the_benefit_of_declaring_a_functions/)