# Types in object destructing from async function return in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Given a function that returns an object promise with a boolean & string:

```
const test = () => {
   return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
       resolve({ result: false, error: 'This is an error' });
   })
}
```

I try to destruct these couple of values into constants:

```
const { result, error } = await test();
```

However, I always get these Typescript errors:

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations, but the only one working is adding the 'any' type, which I believe we should always avoid.

Any idea to define the right types without getting error?

Comment: May need to put a response type on the test method so it knows what it returns.

Comment: Wrapping your const { result, error }... in an async IIFE, it does work for me. Is your surrounding function async ? These are errors within VSCode right ?

Comment: The callback function `async (resolve) => {` doesnt have to be async.

Comment: Also not sure if typescript can deduce the type of the promise from the resolve call, guess you have to type it with `new Promise<{ /*...*/ }>(...)`

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate. I believe the correct syntax is:
`const { result, error }: {result: any; error: any} = await test();` I used `any` because I am not sure what the type for "result" and "error" are.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672807/types-in-object-destructuring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types in object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672807/types-in-object-destructuring)

Comment: Your function could be simplified as `const test = async () => { result: false, error: 'this is an error' };` There is seldom a good reason to use the Promise constructor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck no, all types are optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you should add the type as the generic parameter to the promise - i.e `new Promise<MyType>(...)` Example:

```js
type MyPromiseResult = { result: boolean, error: string };

const test = () => {
   return new Promise<MyPromiseResult>((resolve) => {
       resolve({ result: false, error: 'This is an error' });
   })
}

async function doThing() {
  const { result, error } = await test();
  type ResultType = typeof result; // boolean
  type ErrorType = typeof error; // string
}
```

Comment: That's it! I was actually using 
'interface TraceResult {
    result: boolean,
    error: string
}'
but didn't add the type into the promise. Both ways (type or interface) work.

Answer (score 2):

Give your response a type

`return new Promise<{ result: boolean, error: string }>((resolve) => {})`