# Is there a way to put a type assertion in an import statement?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Got some code in `./fooApi.ts`. But I have a mock for it in `__mocks__` -- this is a way to make sure that the [mock version of your code is imported](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) when using mocks in Jest. This means that when the code runs the actual type of the thing imported will be `jest.Mock`. But TS doesn't know about the mocks. So I need to cast them with `as`:

```
import { createUrl, getToken } from './fooApi';
const mockedCreateUrl = createUrl as jest.Mock;
const mockedGetToken = getToken as jest.Mock;
```

OK TS is happy with that. But I'm wondering if I can do it in one line. I don't see anything on the [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) page about this.

Read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672914/30946) and tried:

```
import { createUrl, getToken } : {createUrl: jest.Mock, getToken: jest.Mock } from './fooApi';
```

Which resulted in `TS1005: 'from' expected.`  at the first colon.

Any way to turn those 3 lines into one?

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, at "compile" time, no way to tell `jest` that you are importing a mocked module or actual module. Only you know that `./fooApi` is already mocked.

You can cast by `as` operator as your 1st option. But, if you are working with `ts-jest`, I can suggest a way to cast the `fooApi` type to mock - use `mocked` function from `ts-jest/untils`:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import fooApi from './fooApi';

describe('fooApi', () => {
  let fooApiMocked: jest.Mocked<typeof fooApi>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fooApiMocked = mocked(fooApi);

    // fooApiMocked.createUrl, fooApiMocked.getToken are jest.Mock
  });
});
```

Comment: well it's a week later and this is the only answer, but I'm gonna wait a bit to mark it as the answer