# How do I destructure an object while renaming the destrucuted variable and assign it to an interface?

Tags: typescript, types, destructuring

**EDIT:** VLAZ's link's accepted answer was helpful - [Types in object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672807/types-in-object-destructuring)

---

None of the other questions I read before making this post applied to what I'm looking for, I think.

For this example I'm using axios to make a GET request to jsonplaceholder.

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
axios.get(url).then((res) => {})
```

The res object has a `data` property, which I want to destructure and call it `todo`

Without typescript, I would have this:

```js
axios.get(url).then((res) => {
  const { data: todo } = res;
  const ID = todo.id;
  const title = todo.title;
  const completed = todo.completed;
  console.log(ID, title, completed)
});
```

It works, but I want to make an interface for the `todo` variable:

```js
interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

**How do I cast the todo variable to this interface so that I have autocomplete on my editor?**

I tried this:

```
const { data: todo }: Todo = res;
```

But the compiler complains: `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Todo'`

I'm guessing I'm trying to cast the whole `res` object to the interface `Todo`, but I don't know how to keep the destructuring+renaming of the `data` property wile casting it to an interface

Comment: Agreeing with VLAZ, but OP is there a reason you need to destructure rather than just setting `const data: Todo = res.data`? Are you destructuring other variables you haven't shown us here?

Comment: Isn't there any other way of assigning a type to a renamed destrucured property without basically repeating myself? From @VLAZ's suggestion, I could do `const {data: newTodo} : {data: Todo} = res` but wouldn't I just be repeating myself, thus missing the point of a destructure in the first place?

Comment: @JeffBowman just an easy to explain example, in this case res.data would make sense but not really in a real world case scenario where destructuring would make sense.

Comment: @C.Rib what if you had `const { a: foo, b: bar }` - how would you "simply" give both a type in that case?\

Comment: @VLAZ would something like `interface AB { a: IA; b: IB }` work? Otherwise, `const { a: foo, b: bar } : {a: IA, b: IB }` ... I see your point now

Comment: Then you've come up with the same solution you said isn't simple. `const { a: foo, b: bar } : AB` is the same as `const { a: foo, b: bar } : { a: IA, b: IB }` only the type is placed elsewhere. You've still repeated yourself.

Comment: Perfect, you've convinced me. Thanks. Guess sometimes just there isn't a simpler way, not that in this case would make much sense after all. Thanks again. I'll link your link in my post then ask to close it.